# Tax amount calculation function issue

Tags: magento2, sales-order, tax

I have an issue with tax calculation total, you can see image below.
Where can I find the tax amount calculation function?
I find this in template

```
 <td class="admin__total-amount">
   <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->formatPrice($block->getTotal()->getValue()) ?>
 </td>
```

I searched for getTotal function, but i didn't find it in the block class
[image]

Comment: what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: If you are talking about hidden tax then check this: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/tax/hidden-tax-calculation.html

Comment: @AmitSaini no i have 2 taxe rules, i likes to round tax amount for 1st and 2nd taxe before calculate total, i updated the image in the post, you can check that total tax is wrong

Comment: @MTM i have 2 tax rules, example 1st tax amount is 1.9987 And 2nd tax 3.4566 i like to change total calculation cause total is wrong, so i like round 1st tax and 2nd tax

Answer (score 0):

You should study the classes found within the below mention folder

```
vendor\magento\module-tax\Model\Sales\Total\Quote
```

You have to find and select the appropriate class and rewrite the function in your custom module by applying plugin/preference.